# Error 404 en vue-router

Tags: vue.js

Tengo un proyecto en Laravel, que me pidieron pasar a vue, estoy trabajando las rutas con vue-router, me sale error 404 en consola, no sé cual puede ser mi error, les comparto el código:

components/galeria.vue

Aquí no me dejo poner el código, pero tengo la vista dentro de un template normal

router.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

import Galeria from "../components/Galeria.vue";

Vue.use(VueRouter)

const routes = [    
    {
        path: '/inicio/galeriavue',
        name: 'Galeria',
        component: Galeria,
    }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    base: process.env.BASE_URL,
    routes,
  });

export default router;
```

app.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from './router/router'

createApp(App).use(router).mount('#app')
```

App.vue

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <h1>Aqui va el navbar</h1>
        
        <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: En Vue Router 4 ya no se utiliza `mode`, puedes probar cambiándolo por  `history: VueRouter.createWebHistory()`